# sap.ui.model.filter Custom Function "test" not triggering/called

Tags: javascript, filter, sapui5

I am trying to do a custom filter to retrieve everything greater than 11000 (just to try it out). I know I can use the Operator.GT but that's not the purpose here. For some reason, my "test" function is not being called or triggered whatsoever. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I am using UI5 Library 1.68 (tried on 1.65 as well, same result). Any help is appreciated.
Thank you

```
var aFilters = []; 
var oFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter({
    path: "OrderID",
    test: function(oValue){
            return oValue > 11000; 
          }
});

aFilters.push(oFilter);
oOrderList.getBinding("items").filter(aFilters);
```

I tried separating the function as such:

```
var oFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter("OrderID", this._testFunction);

._testFunction(oValue){
    return oValue > 11000;
}
```

The function still wasn't called.

Comment: Is this an OData or a JSONModel?

Comment: @Marc It's an OData Model, I've heard that this method can't be done with Server side data. If that's the case, how would one implement a custom filter function similar to what I'm trying to achieve for OData ?

Comment: `new Filter("OrderID", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.GT, 11000)`

Comment: Or just send the data to the backend, the backend ignores the FilterOperator and just does whatever you want to do

Comment: @Marc thanks for your answer but I said I didn't want to use the GT operator. The < 11000 is just an example for trying to use a custom filter. So is there a way to do a custom filter function on the front-end ?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out, it's not possible to do a custom filter function on the front-end on a oData model (Server). To get around this, add << operationMode: 'Client' >> when binding the table/list as such:

```
items="{ path: 'Orders', parameters: {expand: 'Employee', operationMode: 'Client'} }"
```